# rotate two adjacent elements

Tags: html, css

I have two adjacent elements:

- Hero Div, with a background image
- A 60px high element beneath that

I gave the Hero Div a clip-path, to angle the bottom right corner of the image slightly up. I need the div below that to match the angle, so I gave it a `transform: rotate(x)` property. Only issue is that as the hero div scales with its percentages the transformed div doesn't scale with it, leaving white spaces to the left or right depending on the size.

I am sure this is an easy task for a lot, but I can't think of a way that is suitable for production.

```
div(id="front")
    section(class="hero overlay")
        main
            h1 xxx
    div(class="angled")
```

Imagine the bottom right corner of this gray box above as slanted upwards, so as to create the effect of the box being tilted.

Comment: Tipically, you would find a lot  of help in this forum. However, it is very hard to offer you help without any code or a picture of what you are trying to accomplish.Please share your code or a picture of your desired "output"

Comment: You can answer your own questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
.hero {
        background-image: url(../images/hero.png);
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 250px;
        width: 100%;
}

.angled {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-top: 60px solid color('one');
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        margin-top: -40px;
        transform: rotate(-2.5deg);
        width: 110vw;
        z-index: 99;
}
```

As a classical mobile first approach, the background hero image only gets 250px of a height. The angled div is where the money is at. The padding-bottom along with the z-index prevents the hero image from spilling out on the bottom (hides it). The negative margin-top value pulls the div upwards and aligns it with the bottom left corner of the hero image.

I had the hero image itself angled but decided to take it out so that I don't have to worry about two elements with the same responsive angles.

Hope others see this and take a similar mobile-first approach.